# how ssh to differenet hosts on same network easily

Tags: ssh, login, hostname

we have a lot of servers on the same network, 11.12.13.0/24. I have to ssh to several server a day quite often. Right now I do like this:

```
ssh user@11.12.13.3
ssh user@11.12.13.32
ssh user@11.12.13.56
```

With this simple command there two problems:
1. too long - I always need to type the host space
2. sometimes I forget the address completely

Is there any way to replace the host space with a string? like `ssh user@net3 .. ssh user@net32` maybe I can manually fill up the */etc/hosts* file but is there any more sophisticated solution for this?

Comment: You can use host-based authentication when ssh server use predefined user to log in with ssh-key accordingly to the user's host. Then you can login simply like that: `ssh server1` where `server1` is name assigned to the 11.22.33.44 in the `/etc/hosts`

Answer (score 1):

By default ssh tries to log in with the user account it's currently launched on the host you are connecting from. So, if all of the hosts can same accounts database, there's no need to specify user. Plus, if the DNS is properly configured, including `search` directive in the `/etc/resolv.conf` (or hostnames are configured in the `/etc/hosts` file), you can use the short form

`ssh host`

I cannot propose any shorter way of connecting.

Comment: so would be good to set up a DNS on this network?

Comment: Actually DNS of some sort is required in just any network. :)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest ~/.ssh/config as a solution. Here you can defined how the ssh client connects with any server.

Try

> Host Server01
>
> Hostname 11.12.13.3
>
> User user

Should now be able to connect per

> ssh server01

Comment: yes I would have mentioned ssh config file - but still I need to define for this entry for all the servers

Comment: yes, you need to define it for all servers, but you can also generate this list simply if you have continues list of servers in the address block